# Import passwords stored in CSV file to Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have a bunch of passwords that I have exported to a CSV file and I would like to import all of these passwords to Firefox and sync them across my devices through Firefox Sync. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** This solution no longer works with recent Firefox Quantum.

---

You can use the [Password Exporter add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/).

> This extension allows you to export your saved passwords and disabled login hosts using XML or CSV files that can be imported later.

Despite the name it allows you to import passwords from CSV as well:

[image]

You might need to change the CSV format for it to match the one the add-on requires.

Comment: [Passport Exporter Github](https://github.com/fligtar/password-exporter)

Comment: This extension is no longer suported by latest firefox.

Comment: @Qwertylicious Correct. Can't delete the answer because it's accepted, but I'll stick a warning there.

Comment: Please, if you do find a solution, update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I made an utility that solves this issue: https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass

Comment: It works in Waterfox

Answer (score 6):

Edit (28 Feb 2020): The utility is broken in the latest versions of Firefox (73).

I made an utility that solves this issue: https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass

```
pip install ffpass
ffpass import --from passwords.csv
```

Comment: ffpass appears to be a Python 3 program.  Is it necessary to first install the Python 3 interpreter on one's computer?  With which sub-versions of Python (3.2, 3.3, etc) was ffpass developed and with which versions has it been tested?  In which directory should one launch ffpass?  Does it require additional libraries to run, other than the libraries included in a basic Python 3 installation?

Comment: @AndrewP. Those informations are available on the homepage.

Comment: Please update this answer to indicate that it doesn't work in newer firefox versions