# Import passwords stored in CSV with python

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I tried to import password with an utility in python

from [labo](https://superuser.com/a/1347844/19943):

> I made an utility that solves this issue:
>   https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass

```
pip install ffpass
ffpass import --from passwords.csv
```

But when executing I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ffpass", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ffpass==0.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'ffpass')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ffpass/__init__.py", line 69
    print('password checked', file=sys.stderr)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I'm the author of ffpass. You can also use the issues at https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass/issues

Answer (score 2):

The python code probably requires you to run it using Python version 3 rather than 2.7. Without knowing what system you are running we can't say how to switch to python 3 but you might be able to run

```
python3 ffpass import --from passwords.csv
```

Comment: Author of the tool here. The problem is indeed Python 2.
From https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass: "ffpass requires Python 3.5+ and will work with Firefox 58+".

Comment: @Labo is a special command needed to install it via `pip` for Python3?

Comment: if you are not sure about what pip command corresponds to what version of python, you can use `python3 -m pip install ffpass`

Comment: On Fedora 30 I simply use `pip3 install --user ffpass` and afterwards `ffpass import -f firefox_logins.csv -d .mozilla/firefox/t4jwx2vt.default-release/` . Please adapt filenames accordingly.